# Как использовать WebView и принимать значения из Intent во фрагменте?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, webview, android-intent

Я создал активность с использованием WebView, по определённым причинам мне пришлось переносить код из активности в фрагмент. Тут и начались проблемы.
Код фрагмента:

```
public class DollarFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView mTextView;
    Button mDollarButton;
    WebView mWebView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dollar_fragment, container,
                false);

        mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dollarText);
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
        USD usd = arguments.getParcelable(USD.class.getSimpleName());

        mTextView.setText("Валюта: " + usd.getName() + "\nКурс: " + usd.getValue());

        mDollarButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dollarButton);
        mDollarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.banki.ru/products/currency/cash/moskva/");
                WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mDollarButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    }
                });
            }

        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Первая проблема заключается с методом:

```
 @Override // здесь появляется красное подчёркивание
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()){
        mWebView.goBack();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed(); // тут onBackPressed() выделяется красным
    }
}
```

Вторая проблема связана со строкой:

```
 `Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();`// getIntent() выделяется красным
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас подчеркнута `onBackPressed()` потому что данная функция в фрагменте недоступна насколько я знаю. Для этих целей нужно ловить нажатия на кнопки так:

```
fragment.getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
fragment.getView().requestFocus();
fragment.getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} );
```

А проблема с `bundle` в том что нет возможности сделать `getIntent()` что вам и говорит среда. Для получения данных из bundle нужно сделать так:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
   int myInt = bundle.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Ну и дальше уже получаете то что передаете.

Comment: Большое спасибо!)